# SQL UPDATE TABLE from SELECT query from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have bd `hf3` and 5 tables there:
`active_preset` with columns (id , preset_id)
`preset` with columns (id , birja_id, trend_id, fractal, interval_up)
`birja` with columns (id , name)
`trend` with columns (id , name)
`uq_active_preset` with columns (id , birja, trend, fractal, interval_up)

In table `preset` I have a few records. Some of them are in table `active_preset` by foreign key preset_id. In table `active_preset` a few records exist once , a few more than once.

I need to update table `uq_active_preset` with records from table `active_preset` disregarding repetitions of records if they are present.

I did query from `active_preset` and it works good:

```
SELECT 
    b.name AS birja, p.fractal AS fractal , tre.name AS trend, p.interval_up AS interval_up  
FROM hf3.active_preset AS ap
INNER JOIN hf3.preset AS p on p.id = ap.preset_id
INNER JOIN hf3.birja AS b on b.id = p.birja_id
INNER JOIN hf3.trend AS tre on tre.id = p.trend_id
GROUP BY b.name, p.fractal, tre.name, p.interval_up
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

But I don't know how to update `uq_active_preset`

I tried this and it returns syntax error:1064 :

```
UPDATE hf3.uq_active_preset uap SET 
  uap.birja = st.birja ,
  uap.fractal = st.fractal,
  uap.trend = st.trend,
  uap.interval_up = st.interval_up,
 FROM (SELECT b.name AS birja, p.fractal AS fractal , tre.name AS trend, p.interval_up AS interval_up  
        from hf3.active_preset AS ap
        INNER JOIN hf3.preset AS p on p.id = ap.preset_id
        INNER JOIN hf3.birja AS b on b.id = p.birja_id
        INNER JOIN hf3.trend AS tre on tre.id = p.trend_id
        GROUP BY b.name, p.fractal, tre.name, p.interval_up
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
        ) st
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server (MS SQL). Remove non-matched tag.

Comment: Error 1064 claims that you use MySQL. If so then study [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) -> "Multiple-table syntax".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you make an update using `from` is like you join the updated table with your query result. So, you need also a `where` statement in order to tell where those two are connected. Also, don't use alias of your updated table on `set` statement.
You need something like that:

```
UPDATE hf3.uq_active_preset uap SET birja=st.birja,fractal=st.fractal,trend=st.trend,interval_up=st.interval_up
 FROM (SELECT b.name AS birja, p.fractal AS fractal , tre.name AS trend, p.interval_up AS interval_up  
        from hf3.active_preset AS ap
        INNER JOIN hf3.preset AS p on p.id = ap.preset_id
        INNER JOIN hf3.birja AS b on b.id = p.birja_id
        INNER JOIN hf3.trend AS tre on tre.id = p.trend_id
        GROUP BY b.name, p.fractal, tre.name, p.interval_up
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
        ) st
where uap.fkey=st.fkey
```